# Using multiple parameters in URL in express

Tags: node.js, express

I am using Express with Node and I have a requirement in which the user can request the URL as: `http://myhost/fruit/apple/red`.

Such a request will return a JSON response.

The JSON data, before the above call looks like:

```
{
    "fruit": {
        "apple": "foo"
    }
}
```

With the above request, the response JSON data should be:

```
{
    "apple": "foo",
    "color": "red"
}
```

I have configured express to route as follows:

```
app.get('/fruit/:fruitName/:fruitColor', function(request, response) {
    /*return the response JSON data as above using request.params.fruitName and 
request.params.fruitColor to fetch the fruit apple and update its color to red*/
    });
```

But this does not work. I am unsure of how to pass multiple parameters, that is, I am unsure if `/fruit/:fruitName/:fruitColor` is the correct way to do this. Is it?

Answer (score 177, accepted):

```
app.get('/fruit/:fruitName/:fruitColor', function(req, res) {
    var data = {
        "fruit": {
            "apple": req.params.fruitName,
            "color": req.params.fruitColor
        }
    }; 

    send.json(data);
});
```

If that doesn't work, try using console.log(req.params) to see what it is giving you.

Comment: Do you know if something like this is possible? 
`/fruit/:fruitName/vegetable/:vegetableName'`

Comment: sure. just do it like that then do `req.params.fruitName` and `req.params.vegetableName`

Comment: It works, but it happens that static resources will be addressed under `/fruit` in this case like `/fruit/js/main.js` where I have `public/js/main.js` as my static files folder.

Comment: this does not work when one of the parameters is missing

Comment: @chovy what is the correct query string to call such an endpoint 

?fruitName=${fruitName}&fruitColor=${fruitColor}

Answer (score 43):

For what you want I would've used

```js
    app.get('/fruit/:fruitName&:fruitColor', function(request, response) {
       const name = request.params.fruitName 
       const color = request.params.fruitColor 
    });
```

or better yet

```js
    app.get('/fruit/:fruit', function(request, response) {
       const fruit = request.params.fruit
       console.log(fruit)
    });
```

where fruit is a object. So in the client app you just call

```
https://mydomain.dm/fruit/{"name":"My fruit name", "color":"The color of the fruit"}
```

and as a response you should see:

```js
    //  client side response
    // { name: My fruit name, color:The color of the fruit}
```

Comment: This seems to work just fine and is more extensible if you add params later.  I did a JSON.stringify on the client side when building the URL and a JSON.parse on the server in the routing.

Comment: Ah, you're correct. I forgot to add JSON's .parse and .stringify to my suggested answer but I do the same too when passing an object as a parameter so I am sure that I am passing the correct form of the object as a string.

Comment: Please explain to me how does this work? Giving a stringified JSON as parameter to a GET request. This seems like a really bad idea. If the JSON exceeds the GET char limit then what are you going to do ? Also if the JSON contains some value that breaks the URL encoding it will break (but that's easily fixable though).

Answer (score 7):

Both of the way is correct you can use any of them
First way

```
app.get('/fruit/:one/:two', function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.params.one, req.params.two)
});
```

Another way using & symbol

```
app.get('/fruit/:one&:two', function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.params.one, req.params.two)
});
```