# How to prevent express server from serving api routes from the static folder

Tags: node.js, express, routes

Hi I need some help with how express handles routes.

In setting up my express app, I have something like this:
   `app.use(express.static('public'));`

Next, I mount some api routes:

```
app.use('/api', myrouter);
app.get('*', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve('public/index.html'));
});
```

But, when the frontend requests data via an api route, e.g. at '**localhost:3000/api/things**', I am seeing in the Express debug logs that at some point (unsure when) it actually tries to serve this request as a static file, like:

```
send stat "C:\myproject\public\api\things" +230ms
```

Even though this folder doesn't exist in 'public' and should be solely handled by my api. FYI, the handler for `/api/things` route is only implemented for the GET method, and does get invoked at some point.

**How do I stop express server from also trying to serve api requests from the static folder?**

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question... which appears to be a duplicate of this one:
[`express.static()` keeps routing my files from the route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28143419/express-static-keeps-routing-my-files-from-the-route)

So the answer is this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28143812/8670745

In short, the app.use() declarations that mount your api routers should appear **before** the app.use() statements which tell express.static where to serve your static files from. This way, the latter acts as a catchall AFTER api route handling is done. Router engine order matters...

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is misinformed, or rather you've misinterpreted the problem. Your original configuration:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + 'public'));
app.use('/api', myrouter);
```

Looks absolutely fine because there's no clash between the routes. The threads you've linked too aren't really the same, and I can see why moving the routes in those cases would have worked.

The only thing I'd say is your path to your static folder isn't reliable, you should really use `path.join`, or actually in your case you can just do `express.static('public')` - express will infer the folder your app is served from.

Comment: actually... What I have right now in my project is `express.static('public')` like u suggest... I'm not sure why i have the __dirname in the question; will correct. Regardless: even with the simpler form, when the express.static line appears **before** the api router mount, I see the express debug `send stat ...` line with the api path. Unless that's express just "thinking", and nothing is actually being served. If so this question is moot and should be deleted. I may've had some other problem which has now magically resolved itself.

Comment: @yen well express uses regexes internally to match routes, given your static route is on the root of the app perhaps that's the issue - any route would effectively match (as it would resolve to /). FWIW that looks like a statsd logger, try turning on [debug logging](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/debugging.html) for a more detailed view of what's actually going on. I'm