# req.query only detecting a single parameter from URL

Tags: node.js, url, express

I have the following test code,

```
app.use(function(req,res,next)
{

console.log("Params : " + req.params);

console.log("Path : " + req.path);

console.log("Query :" +req.query);


for(var params in req.query)
{

    console.log(params);
}

res.end("processed");

});
```

whenever I generate a request with the following url

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/path/resource/myname?user=alanz&password=alpacasocks
```

I obtain the output

```
Params : [object Object]
Path : /path/resource/name
Query :[object Object]
user
```

It does not seem to detect the second query variable. Generating the request with curl.

Comment: What is the value of `user` param? Have you tried with a browser instead of curl?

Comment: I have not tried a browser since I am using cloud9 (unsure if it allows public connections) but I will when I get a chance.  I tried the solutions below and cannot get it to work, however I am starting to suspect it is an issue with curl rather than node

Comment: Try to escape `&`. Try to print value of the parameters e.g. `req.query[params]`.

Comment: Came home, tried it with my browser and it works like a charm. This is an issue with curl, or curl within the cloud9 development environment

Answer (score 2):

For me, curl command worked when the url was enclosed in `""`

```
curl "http://127.0.0.1:8080/path/resource/myname?user=alanz&password=alpacasocks"
```

returned both user and password in req.query

Answer (score 1):

```
var data = req.query;
```

req.query would yield like following object

```
{user:"alanz", password: "alpacasocks"}
```

You can extract username and password by dot notation

```
va username = data.user;      //print "alanz"
va password = data.password;  //print "alpacasocks"
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since in [express' api](http://expressjs.com/api.html#req.query) it stands like this:

> ```
> // GET /shoes?order=desc&shoe[color]=blue&shoe[type]=converse
>
> req.query.order
> // => "desc"
>
> req.query.shoe.color
> // => "blue"
>
> req.query.shoe.type
> // => "converse"
> ```

I think it would be like this:

```
// GET /users?user[name]=myname&user[password]=mypassword

req.query.user.name
// => "myname"

req.query.user.password
// => "mypassword
```

Because you are querying for 2 values of the same object, and not for 2 different objects. Maybe you just want to use it as params, like in [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15128849/using-multiple-parameters-in-url-in-express).

PS: In any case, I wouldn't treat a password like that in any real scenario.