# I can't create a route path with optionals strings and parameters - ExpressJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I want to be able to write a route in the following ways (I have 3 parameters: **lapsnumber**, **time** and **breaktime**):

- /20minutes
- /1laps-20minutes-10secondsbreak
- /2laps-20minutes

My current code is this one:

```
router.get('/(:lapsnumber-)?:time(-:breaktime)?', function(req,res,next) {
  res.render('timer', {
    lap: req.params.lapsnumber,
    time: req.params.time,
    breaks: req.params.breaktime
  });
})
```

How can I do that? Thank you so much! :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Express.js routing: optional spat param?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10020099/express-js-routing-optional-spat-param)

Answer (score 0):

```
router.get('/somethingWithTime/:lapsnumber/:time/:breaktime', 
function(req,res,next) {
  res.render('timer', {
    lap: req.params.lapsnumber,
    time: req.params.time,
    breaks: req.params.breaktime
  });
})
```

[this problème were alredy solved here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15128849/using-multiple-parameters-in-url-in-express)