# How to pass multiple GET parameters to Express?

Tags: node.js, express, get, routes

I'm a bit new to Node.js and writing some REST APIs in Node.js. For one of my API ,I need to pass 2 parameters to get the data from database.I have achieved it using single parameter but not more than 2. can anybody help me please ?

Here's my code

```
app.get('/getData/:receiver_id&:sender_id',function(req,res){
    connection.query('SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE sender_id=? AND receiver_id=?',[req.params.sender_id],[req.params.receiver_id],function(error,results,fields){
        if(error) throw error;
        else {
        res.json({'result':results})
        console.log(JSON.stringify(results))
        }
    });
});
```

And I keep getting this error in the console

```
> /var/www/html/chatApp/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:80
        throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors
              ^
TypeError: Object 1 has no method 'apply'
    at Query.Sequence.end (/var/www/html/chatApp/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:83:24)
    at Query.ErrorPacket (/var/www/html/chatApp/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Query.js:90:8)
    at Protocol._parsePacket (/var/www/html/chatApp/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:278:23)
    at Parser.write (/var/www/html/chatApp/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:76:12)
    at Protocol.write (/var/www/html/chatApp/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:38:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/var/www/html/chatApp/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:91:28)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/var/www/html/chatApp/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:502:10)
    at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (_stream_readable.js:710:14)
    at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:92:17)
```

Comment: You've added exactly the same message; please remove it - and make sure the code IS updated and server IS restarted.

Comment: it still shows the same error

Comment: Please show how you've rewritten the code then.

Comment: your edited code is incorrect you have to bind params into one array not in two different array. It should be `[req.params.sender_id,req.params.receiver_id] instead of [req.params.sender_id],[req.params.receiver_id]`

Comment: Why on Earth do you still use two arrays to pass the params into MySQL in the _edited_ code? What's the edit then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The route-defining pattern in your code is fine (check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15128849/using-multiple-parameters-in-url-in-express) for alternatives), the problem is different: you should use a single array to pass all the values for query ([**docs**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql#performing-queries)), not a separate array for each param. For example:

```
connection.query(
   'SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE sender_id=? AND receiver_id=?',
   [req.params.sender_id, req.params.receiver_id],
   function(/*...*/)
);
```

Note that the error message here is actually helpful: `Object 1 has no method apply` means that MySQL package attempts to treat your param as a function (a callback).

Comment: how to solve that error ? because it shows `/var/www/html/chatApp/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:80
        throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors`

Comment: Have you changed the code the way described? If so, what exactly's the message?

Comment: yeah I changed the code ,but when I call it from the app it still shows the same error on the consile

Comment: Ok, what's the error msg? You've shown just the first line of it.

Comment: If I try this code ,the url becomes http://104.131.162.126:3000/getData?receiver_id=1&sender_id=2  and it shows the same log in console .What do i do to solve this error ?

Answer (score 1):

Try in this way
Form the url in this fromat  `localhost:portno/getData/:receiver_id/:sender_id`             `Ex: localhost:portno/getdata/12/21`

```
app.get('/getData/:receiver_id/:sender_id',function(req,res){
    connection.query('SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE sender_id=? AND receiver_id=?',[req.params.sender_id, req.params.receiver_id],function(error,results,fields){
        if(error) throw error;
        else {
        res.json({'result':results})
        console.log(JSON.stringify(results))
        }
    });
});
```

Other way

```
'Ex: localhost:portno/getdata/12&21`
 app.get('/getData/:receiver_id&:sender_id',function(req,res){
        connection.query('SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE sender_id=? AND receiver_id=?',[req.params.sender_id, req.params.receiver_id],function(error,results,fields){
            if(error) throw error;
            else {
            res.json({'result':results})
            console.log(JSON.stringify(results))
            }
        });
    });
```

One More Way to do This

```
app.get('/getData/:receiver_id&:sender_id',function(req,res){
        connection.query('SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE sender_id=? AND receiver_id=?',req.params.sender_id, req.params.receiver_id,function(error,results,fields){
            if(error) throw error;
            else {
            res.json({'result':results})
            console.log(JSON.stringify(results))
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: well i tried this too , but it still shows the same error

Comment: Your answer is misleading; there's nothing wrong with writing the path the way the OP did, the problem is in binding code.

Comment: Just copy paste my code in your project and form the correct url then test the API@Neha

Comment: @PrashantGupta tried both the ways but still the same error

Comment: I added one more way to do this  please try @Neha

Answer (score 0):

```
app.get('/getData/:receiver_id/:sender_id',function(req,res){
    connection.query('SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE sender_id=? AND receiver_id=?',[req.params.sender_id, req.params.receiver_id],function(error,results,fields){
        if(error) throw error;
        else {
            res.json({'result':results})
            console.log(JSON.stringify(results))
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: give me test url for how to pass parameters

Comment: 104.131.162.126:3000/getData/1/2