# Multiple inputs through URL in Node JS

Tags: angularjs, node.js, query-string

I am trying to read multiple inputs from URL (may vary with every request) in NODEJS.

For eg: `www.blahblah.com/api/abc/xyz/pop/god/` is requested,

I want to take `'abc','xyz','pop','god'` and process each individually. the script i am passing it to, takes the input and passes it to a perl script to get the output.

I am using AngularJS and NodeJS.

any suggetions.

Comment: What have you tried so far and why didn't that work?

Comment: What do you mean by multiple inputs? Can you try to elaborate your question and the context of use? Do you mean to read req.params?

Comment: Please be more specific and a bit elaborate. If all you want to do is just use the parts of the URL, you might just use a `substring` method.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using multiple parameters in URL in express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15128849/using-multiple-parameters-in-url-in-express)

Comment: @Sreehari  yes req.params.

Comment: @PrashantGupta No.. i saw that, its not what i need, as there number of params is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I'll say.
Make the ajax call with Json Data

```js
$.ajax({
  type : "POST",
  url : "/yourServiceUrl",
  data :{
    data1 : data1Val,
    data2: data2Val,
    .
    .
    .
    datan: datanVal
  }
}).done((result)=>{});
```

Fetch the data in backed using

```js
let data1 = req.body.data1;
let data2 = req.body.data2;
.
.
.
.
let datan = req.body.datan;
```

Regular expressions may also be used, and can be useful if you have very specific restraints, for example the following would match "GET /commits/71dbb9c" as well as "GET /commits/71dbb9c..4c084f9".

```js
app.get(/^\/commits\/(\w+)(?:\.\.(\w+))?$/, function(req, res){
  var from = req.params[0];
  var to = req.params[1] || 'HEAD';
  res.send('commit range ' + from + '..' + to);
});
```

This should solve your problem :)